# define more than 1 email address for a linux user

Tags: linux, email, squirrelmail

How I can create  more than 1 email address for a Linux user e.g. customer. 
default email address is customer[at]domain[dot]com but I want to add info[at]domain[dot]com.
I use squirrelmail and I'm not planing to install a control panel.

How to manually add another email address?

Comment: squirrelmail is just a web interface, providing webmail I assume you have this backing onto another MTA? you need to provide the MTA in use, as what you are after is called aliasing; and this can vary depending on the MTA in use.

Comment: Ok, Dovecot provides a pickup interface (imap pop3 etc ...) are you using postfix, sendmail or something else to handel the sending and receipt of email ?

Comment: Thanks, I use sendmail as MTA. and I see a lot of mail aliases in /etc/aliases, I think they are for logging right? so how can I create another mail for specific user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have highlighted you are using sendmail as the MTA.

You will want to edit the file /etc/aliases an run newaliases upon completion to trigger a database rebuild.

the format of addition (assuming same domain) would be: `info: real_user`

Note: one of my deploys has `info:           postmaster` you may wish to remove this.

Comment: when I'm sending emails it still uses customer@domain.com as sender not info@domain.com. is there anyway to fix this? thanks

Comment: Your customer should change that in their email client settings.